# SDE of futures price under non-constant interest rate and volatility process

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, futures, black76

I'm trying to figure out the form of the SDE of futures price under the risk neutral measure, when stock price follows GBM:
                $dS_{t}=r_{t}S_{t}d_{t}+\sigma_{t}S_{t}dW_{t}$

When $r_{t}=r$, and $\sigma_{t}=\sigma$, it's trivial that futures price $F_{t,T}$ follows GBM:
                $dF_{t}=\sigma F_{t}dW_{t}$
as futures price is a martingale.

I wonder if we can derive an explicit form of SDE for futures price when interest rate and volatility are random processes. I tried myself but failed to do so.

Comment: I do not think it is possible for general random $r$ and $\sigma$. However, it is possible for random $r$ and $\sigma$ with certain specific dynamic forms.